# Missing Particle System Panel from Properties Menu

Tags: particles, properties

New to Blender. Using 3.2.1 and following a tutorial for particles. My properties menu does not have the particle system panel.

I have selected the model, and it still does not appear. I have switched between layout and modeling windows and it doesn't show up in any.

As far as I know I've never changed any of the workspace layout so it should be on the Blender default.

[image]

Comment: You have a text object there. Text is using curves, only a mesh object can have a particle system so you have to convert your text. So either right-click on your object and from the context menu choose _Convert To > Mesh_ or from the viewport menu choose _Object > Convert > Mesh_. But be aware that you cannot edit the text anymore after converting.

Comment: You can't add a particle system to a text object unless you convert it to a mesh first via the Object > Convert > Mesh menu. The Particle system icon will then appear in the properties sidebar.

Comment: Thanks- I thought i had already converted it but I must have forgotten.... oops